# Show title of referenced node in node template

Tags: theming, nodes, entities

I'm working on a node template for my content types and use [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to reference my content with each other. THe machine name of my entity reference field is *og_group_ref*. In my node template I used `print_r(get_defined_vars())` to show all existing varialbes to select variables I need. When I look for *og_group_ref* I only get the *target_id* of that reference:

```
[og_group_ref] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [target_id] => 65
                    )
            )
```

So, my question is how do I get the title of that referenced node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if I remember node structure right:

- Load node by id into $node
- Put title to $node_title

  $node = node_load(og_group_ref[0][target_id]);

  $node_title = $node->title;

All you need is to get og_group_ref object/element